# Puerto abierto no responde en windows server 2012R2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, windows-server-2012, firewall

Buen día, espero puedan ayudarme con mi problema de antemano muchas gracias.

Abrí un puerto en mi Windows Server 2012 R2, para probar una aplicación de spring boot, este puerto lo abrí desde las configuraciones del firewall de windows donde agregue una nueva regla y el numero del puerto. **El puerto se agrego correctamente mostrando el icono verde y disponible.**

El link de la pagina donde me guie para abrir el puerto es este

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.parallels.com/blogs/ras/configuring-windows-server-firewall-for-parallels-ras/)

Para revisar si el puerto esta en Listening realice este comando usando powershell

```
>netstat -an
```

Pero **no me muestra mi puerto abierto el cual es 8443 de tipo TCP**

También realice este comando para ver si el puerto esta abierto

```
>telnet 173.20.39.40 8443


Resultado de este comando es el siguiente:

Connecting To 173.20.39.40... Could not open connecting to the host, on port 8443: Connect failed
```

El servicio que requiero levantar en este puerto es un microservicio. el puerto esta configurado dentro de mi application.properties de esta manera.

```
server.port:8443
```

Al ejecutar mi microservicio con extension .jar en la consola me marca el siguiente error

```
>java -jar administracion.jar
```

El mensaje que muestra es el siguiente:

```
*******************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
*******************************



Description:
   The tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port alredy be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
```

**¿Alguien sabría como se puede solucionar esto para que el puerto se abra y responda al realizarle un telnet?**

Comment: Falta saber cómo está configurado el servicio que esperas que responda en el servidor. Si el firewall tiene la regla definida correctamente, no hay más restricciones.

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, el servicio que quiero que responda en ese puerto es un microservicio realizado en springboot. En este microservicio solo configuro el puerto en un archivo llamado application properties pero al instalarlo marca un error respecto al puerto y al realizarle un telnet al puerto puedo ver que la conexión a este puerto falla.

Comment: Entonces es el servicio el que está mal. Te toca compartirnos cómo estás configurando el puerto y qué error te da _respecto al puerto_ para que no nos toque adivinar

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, edite mi pregunta en el que muestro el error que me muestra, así como la linea donde configuro mi archivo con el puerto.

Comment: Prueba ejecutar `netstat -ano` y verifica en el Monitor de Recursos a cual programa pertenece el PID que este asociado al puerto.

Comment: Hola @RobertoEMoran he realizado el comando que me comentas en powershell y no observo el puerto, ya que aun no existe aplicación usando este puerto. El puerto abierto esta limpio, en este puerto quiero mi levantar mi microservicio, este puerto ya lo abrí desde la configuración del firewall pero al momento de verificar si este responde me manda el error colocado en la publicación.